# Binary Search Tree not deleting Node

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes

I have created a `Binary Search Tree` and am trying to delete specific nodes after adding them. I can successfully `delete` about 5 `Nodes` but when I try to delete a `Node with id 109` it just ignores it and nothing happens. I have tried many methods to delete it and it just does not work.

```
myBinaryTree.deleteNode(myBinaryTree.root, 109);
```

Here is the `delete` method in my Binary Tree.

```
public Node deleteNode(Node root, int ID){

    if (root == null)  return root;
    if (ID < root.ID)
        root.leftChild = deleteNode(root.leftChild, ID);
    else if (ID > root.ID)
        root.rightChild = deleteNode(root.rightChild, ID);

    else
    {
        if (root.leftChild == null)
            return root.rightChild;
        else if (root.rightChild == null)
            return root.leftChild;

        root.ID = minValue(root.rightChild);
        root.rightChild = deleteNode(root.rightChild, root.ID);
    }

    return root;
}


int minValue(Node root)
{
    int minv = root.ID;
    while (root.leftChild != null)
    {
        minv = root.leftChild.ID;
        root = root.leftChild;
    }
    return minv;
}
```

And my `Node`:

```
public class Node {
    int ID;
    Dancer.Gender gender;
    int height;

    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;

    Node(int ID, Dancer.Gender gender, int height) {

        this.ID = ID;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.height = ID;

    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

}
```

The `ID` works as intended meaning the method `deleteNode` gets correct ID, it just does not delete it.

Here is a picture of a the tree I am trying to delete from:

[image]

If more information on how I add the nodes etc is needed then I can provide that aswell. It is just so wierd that it all works perfectly until I try to delete node with `ID = 109`.

Comment: Did you debug through it? I would suspect `ID > root.ID` is not true, or not going to the right-hand side.

Comment: Something that you will probably have to fix later but still : `this.height = ID;` it's from Node constructor.

Comment: @achAmháin it ends up in `else if (root.rightChild == null) return root.leftChild`

Comment: @dbl it is intended at the moment but will do later on

Comment: So that means it is incorrectly going past `else if (ID > root.ID)`. Can you provide the `Node` code you pass to `deleteNode`?

Comment: @achAmháin actually I think I got it by just adding this line `waitingLineWithFemales.root =...`, even though I am not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

By the way, how did you verify that the node was not deleted ?
I just checked your code and printed inorder traversal. And it works fine.

```
// This is java code.
void inorder(Node root){
    if (root ==null)return;
    inorder(root.leftChild);
    System.out.print(root.ID + "  ");
    inorder(root.rightChild);
}

// verify deletion by printing inorder traversal before and after
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // creating the tree
    Node root = new Node(60);
    root.leftChild = new Node(40);
    root.rightChild = new Node(109);
    root.leftChild.leftChild = new Node(20);
    root.leftChild.rightChild = new Node(49);

    inorder(root); // Printing before deleting
    System.out.println();
    myBinaryTree.root = deleteNode(myBinaryTree.root, 109); // delete the node and collect the new reference of the root.
    inorder(root); // Printing after tree
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: By printing out the remaining Nodes and checking if 109 is still among them, I am not sure why but `waitingLineWithFemales.root =...` actually removed it from the tree, even tho it was not needed for the previous ones

Comment: could you show the code which for "printing out the remaining Nodes" ?

Comment: And by using your inorder it still leaves the 109 there, but the reference part worked

Comment: reference part worked, but just deleting without reference is still not working

Comment: But it is fine, I can use the reference, If you change your answer back to the reference part I can accept it